# How to show the value inside the handler using bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-slider

I am using [boostrap slider](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) and this is how i am implementing it:

```
$("#yearSlider").slider({step: 20000, min: 0, max: 200000})
```

How do I get the value inside the handler rather than having it in the tool tip?

Expected result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use value property:

Example: try to run this code in console on the page you linked (http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/):

```
document.getElementById('ex1').value
```

you'll see the value is returned correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value on the slide event in the following way:

```
$("#yearSlider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
  $("#yearSlider .slider-handle").text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82w4vg4q/).

Css on the slider handle is a bit funny - it looks like its positioned absolutely, so there may be a better way to style it using the js library's options.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you find out how to properly style the handle? essentially, you need it to be much bigger to fit the text you're wanting to put in there.  The larger slider was off center unless I changed the top attribute, but I'm not sure how well that would work on a real page with absolute positioning.

Comment: yes i did, made the handle round bigger, then set a span inside to contain the value and positioned it absolute to center the text, that's also why the accepted answer helped as i could do  `$("#yearSlider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
  $(".slider-handle").html("<span>"+document.getElementById('yearSlider').value+"</span>");
 });`

Comment: you can also do $("input#yearSlider").val() to get the value of the slider.  my fiddle does this on document.ready

Comment: true but i needed a <span> to style it